# Installing ROS on Ubuntu 14.04 in BeagleBone Black

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, beagleboneblack, ros

I installed the image of ubuntu 14.04 for beaglebone black from following:
https://rcn-ee.net/rootfs/2015-02-19/flasher/BBB-eMMC-flasher-ubuntu-14.04.2-console-armhf-2015-02-19-2gb.img.xz

After that i follow the steps given on ROS site to install it on Ubuntu-arm but when i try `sudo apt-get update` it gives error like:

```
Get:1 http://repos.rcn-ee.net trusty InRelease
Get:2 http://repos.rcn-ee.net trusty-updates InRelease                     
99% [1 InRelease gpgv 199 B] [Connecting to ports.ubuntu.com] [Connecting to diSplitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/repos.rcn-ee.net_ubuntu_dists_trusty_InReIgn http:/repos.rcn-ee.net trusty InRelease                                   
E: GPG error: http:/repos.rcn-ee.net trusty InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the thread [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/611209/gpg-error-http-repos-rcn-ee-net)

And look for Kartek's solution (provided by RobertCNelson):

```
sudo apt-get install rcn-ee-archive-keyring
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't done so yet you should try installing the key for the repository:

wget http://repos.rcn-ee.net/ubuntu/conf/repos.rcn-ee.net.gpg.key -O - | apt-key add -